What is the purpose of the last sentence in [dcl.fct.spec]/4?
[dcl.fct.spec]/4:

In an explicit-specifier, the constant-expression, if supplied,
shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool
([expr.const]). The explicit-specifier explicit without a
constant-expression is equivalent to the explicit-specifier
explicit(true). If the constant expression evaluates to true, the
function is explicit. Otherwise, the function is not explicit. A (
token that follows explicit is parsed as part of the
explicit-specifier.

What is the purpose of the last sentence above? Isn't this obvious from the first definition of the grammar term explicit-specifier given below?
explicit-specifier:
 explicit ( constant-expression )
 explicit 


Note that struct foo { (foo)(){} }; compiles; and struct foo { explicit (foo)(){} }; fails to compile, because of the above rule making the ( part of the "explicit-specifier".  Without the above rule it would be ambiguous.

The following is valid:
struct A {
    (A)(/*...*/); //1
};

//1 declares a constructor of A with parameter list /*...*/. This is allowed because the grammar for declarators allows adding extra parentheses in various places, e.g. around the declarator-id A.
So then there is a question of how
struct A {
    explicit (A)(/*...*/); //2
};

should be interpreted.
Before C++20 //2 would mean that we have the same constructor signature as in //1, but marked explicit, and the C++20 grammar without the sentence in question would still allow parsing it that way, while parsing (A) as part of the explicit-specifier wouldn't work, because () is not a valid declarator syntax and A is not an expression.
The sentence that you are asking about forces the second interpretation making this ill-formed. The proposal doesn't make a specific argument as to why, but I suppose it is meant to avoid mistakes, since something like
struct A {
    explicit(A) (/*...*/); //3
};

looks like explicit(A) was an explicit-specifier, although per the grammar itself, it wouldn't be parsed that way.
This is also mentioned as breaking change in [diff.cpp17.class]/1.
As far as I can tell, this only makes previously well-formed code ill-formed. I don't think there is any actual ambiguity without that sentence. The only code made ill-formed are declarations with extra parentheses around the declarator-id, which probably nobody uses in practice.

"which probably nobody uses in practice" mandatory xkcd.
